# why my class constructor is considered have the same declaration even though the data type is different?

Tags: android, kotlin

so I have `NotificationKM` class like this

```
class NotificationKM() : Parcelable {

    var notificationID : String = ""
    var creatorID : String = ""
    var creatorName : String = ""
    var title : String = ""
    var body : String = ""
    var createdAt : Date = Calendar.getInstance().time
    var imagePath : String = ""
    var type : String = ""
    var hasBeenRead: Boolean = false


    constructor(dataMessage: MutableMap<String,Any>?) : this() {
        

    }

    constructor(data: MutableMap<String!,String!>) : this() {

    }

}
```

but I have an error:

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same
> JVM signature

[image]

the data type is different, but I have this error. what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because generics in Java (and in Kotlin too as Kotlin produces jvm bytecode) are using type erasure mechanism, so, when your app will be compiled it would be only `Map` with no items type info. Also, nullability has no reflection at bytecode.

I would suggest creating 2 different factory methods with different names: `createFromData` and `createFromMessage`, for example